# Request failed with status code 404, OpenAI Api integration with React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I am following this tutorial: https://blog.gopenai.com/integrating-chatgpt-with-a-react-js-and-node-js-web-application-b58dc3eac51

I have followed all the steps but get this error message when I submit my prompt in the input box:
[image: error-image]

For reference, my files:

ChatGpt.js file:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const ChatGPT = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');
  const [response, setResponse] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const result = await axios.post('', { prompt: input });
      setResponse(result.data.text);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      setResponse('An error occurred while processing your request.');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="input">Input:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="input"
          value={input}
          onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <div>
        <h3>Response:</h3>
        <p>{response}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChatGPT;
```

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const openai = require('openai');
openai.apiKey = "My-API-Key";

app.get('', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});

app.use(express.json());

app.post('', async (req, res) => {
  const prompt = req.body.prompt;

  try {
    const response = await openai.Completion.create({
      engine: 'text-davinci-002',
      prompt: prompt,
      max_tokens: 50,
      n: 1,
      stop: null,
      temperature: 0.5,
    });

    res.json({ text: response.choices[0].text });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred while processing your request.' });
  }
});
```

I am not sure what is causing this error.

Comment: What happens when you hit the endpoint directly via Postman? (or change it to be the GET and hit locahost:3000?prompt=whatever directly from your browser)

Comment: it looks like you are not passing a URL here `const result = await axios.post('', { prompt: input });`